# Set Imageview Height according to ConstraintLayout height

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to design layout in which Imageview height changes according to Constraint layout height.

So I tried to set constraint **app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_name"**,  **app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"** and **android:layout_height="0dp"** to the Imageview but it's not working

It giving me 0dp height of Imageview as Output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rv_item_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp">


        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_item_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/logowithtext_trans"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_name"
            app:riv_corner_radius="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/name"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_item_home"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_share"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_dark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_item_home"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output Image**
[image: Output]

**Desired Image**
[image: Desired Image]

Comment: Could you add image of what you have now ?

Comment: I edited my post with the images @TamirAbutbul

Answer (score 0):

you've limited the bottom of your RoundedImageView to top of the tv_name and bounded the top of tv_name to bottom of the RoundedImageView,the top constraint of tv_name isn't clear, that's why your image view can't detect the size. 
you can create a percent Guideline and limit your views to top and bottom of that.

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

or you can just add DimensionRatio to your roundImageView something like this:

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_item_home"
    app:riv_corner_radius="20dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/sample_img"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,3:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_item_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change constraint in `RoundedImageView` and `TextView` as below:

```
 <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_item_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            ....
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_name" />

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv_name"
      ....
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_item_home"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Comment: I tried it but not working. I have edited my post with the resultant images